# What is an easy way to post to your own blog using OAuth?

Tags: tumblr, oauth

Tumblr updated their API service to use OAuth. I can no loger use my own username and password to post on my own blog, I have to use OAuth.

I am not interested in creating a full blown app, I just want to be able to post on my own blog using their API. What is the easy way to authenticate with OAuth and start posting?

Comment: How are you currently using the API? Most languages have libraries that can handle the OAuth for you fairly easily.

Comment: APIs are really rather developer, and not end user, problems. I suspect that this question really belongs on [so] or, perhaps better, with Tumblr's support.